# What is the best way to determine if a living person in the UK has a will?

Tags: wills, probate

I'm doing some research for a side project where I want to determine whether a living person in the UK has a will or not.

What are your recommendations?

Comment: They're alive, so have you tried asking them?

Comment: As @JAB says, ask them.  The will of someone who's still alive isn't a public record, so you likely can't get it without their consent.  They could even have written it themselves and be keeping it at home, in which case it could be that nobody knows about it except the person themselves (and whoever witnessed it).

Answer (score 1):

Ask them. There is no public record of wills.